# Jest store state and RTL rendered component's onClick event handler different states

Tags: react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm using the following code to test a state-dependent react component using jest and rtl:

```
test("render author, date and image correctly after going next post", async () => {
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
      data: dataReducer
    }
  });
  const Wrapper = ({ children }) => (
    <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
  );
  render(<Post />, { wrapper: Wrapper });

  const getSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockReturnValue(mockPostJSON);
  await store.dispatch(FETCH_POSTS());
  expect(getSpy).toBeCalledWith('https://www.reddit.com/r/EarthPorn/.json');

  const beforeClick = await screen.findByTestId('authorAndDate');
  expect(beforeClick.innerHTML.toString()).toBe(mockPostsList[0].author + ' - ' + mockPostsList[0].date);

  fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Next post'));
        
  const afterClick = await screen.findByTestId('authorAndDate');
  expect(afterClick.innerHTML.toString()).toBe(mockPostsList[1].author + ' - ' + mockPostsList[1].date);
})
```

The problem I'm having is that before the click everything in the store is set up correctly and the authorAndDate element displays the first item in the array of posts.  But after the click is fired the store goes back to the initial state it had before loading the mock data.  I checked within the component's event handler and right before it does anything the state has been reset.  The code is as follows:

```
const handleNextClick = () => {
  store.dispatch(GO_NEXT_POST());
  store.dispatch(FETCH_COMMENTS());
}
```

I've been an hour over the code trying to find something that would reset the state and found nothing.  I'm guessing it's some kind of interaction between jest and rtl but I can't figure out why the store in the test has one state and the store in the component's event handler has another :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, figured it out.  Can't use store.dispatch directly as it's accessing a stale state.  Needed to use the useDispatch hook.  Hope this serves anybody who faces the same problem in the future.